# Linq - How to collect Anonymous Type as Result for a Function

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, anonymous-types

I use c# 4 asp.net and EF 4. I'm precompiling a query, the result should be a collection of Anonymous Type.

At the moment I use this code.

```
public static readonly Func<CmsConnectionStringEntityDataModel, string, dynamic>     
queryContentsList =
CompiledQuery.Compile<CmsConnectionStringEntityDataModel, string, dynamic>
(
    (ctx, TypeContent) => ctx.CmsContents.Where(c => c.TypeContent == TypeContent 
 & c.IsPublished == true & c.IsDeleted == false)
        .Select(cnt => new
      { 
         cnt.Title, 
         cnt.TitleUrl, 
         cnt.ContentId, 
         cnt.TypeContent, cnt.Summary 
      }
            )
   .OrderByDescending(c => c.ContentId));
```

I suspect the RETURN for the FUNCTION `Dynamic` does not work properly and I get this error

Sequence contains more than one element `enter code here`.

I suppose I need to return for my function a Collection of Anonymous Types...

Do you have any idea how to do it? What I'm doing wrong? Please post a sample of code thanks!

Update:

```
    public class ConcTypeContents
        {
            public string Title { get; set; }
            public string TitleUrl { get; set; }
            public int ContentId { get; set; }
            public string TypeContent { get; set; }
            public string Summary { get; set; }
        }

        public static readonly Func<CmsConnectionStringEntityDataModel, string, ConcTypeContents> queryContentsList =
CompiledQuery.Compile<CmsConnectionStringEntityDataModel, string, ConcTypeContents>(
    (ctx, TypeContent) => ctx.CmsContents.Where(c => c.TypeContent == TypeContent & c.IsPublished == true & c.IsDeleted == false)
        .Select(cnt => new ConcTypeContents { cnt.Title, cnt.TitleUrl, cnt.ContentId, cnt.TypeContent, cnt.Summary }).OrderByDescending(c => c.ContentId));
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should not return an anonymous type from a method. Create a concrete type to hold whatever data is currently held in the anonymous type and return that instead.

```
...
.Select(cnt => 
    new ConcType{ 
        Title = cnt.Title, 
        TitleUrl = cnt.TitleUrl, 
        ContentId = cnt.ContentId, 
        TypeContent = cnt.TypeContent,  
        Summary = cnt.Summary })
...
```

where:

```
class ConcType
{
    public string Title {get; set;}
    //etc...
}
```

Comment: I get this error ..... ConcType  it does not implement 'System.Collections.IEnumerable'

Comment: If you add your updated code to the question, it might be easier to tell you what's going on.

Comment: thanks spender, I updated the code, if you have time please let me know.

Comment: Er, you *can* return an anonymous type from a method, you just can't return it strongly-typed. If the method signature is to return `object` or (as here) `dynamic`, `return new { a = 5 };` works just fine. Both the original error and the comment instead suggest a confusion somewhere between *sequences* and *individual objects* .

Comment: AakashM I understand your point. Do you have a pragmatical way to solve it? Thanks

Comment: Pragmatical way is not using anonymous type when you must return it from the method. Abusing `dynamic` for this scenario is just ugly hack.

Comment: thanks Ladislav for your comment, I know dynamic does not look good and also does not work in my case. I appreciate your comment on this. I will consider all your options :-).